# Is it possible to simplify this LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have `ModelState` with `FluentValidaiton` on top of it. If the view model is not valid I would like to simply return list of validation errors, nothing more. I've made this LINQ statement and it works fine, however I wonder if it can be written in a shorter (better) way.

I know that I can extract extension method and I will, the question is more about optimizing LINQ statement itself.

The LINQ in question:

```
return ModelState.Select(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Errors).SelectMany(x => x.Select(z => z.ErrorMessage));
```

`return ModelState` Output:

```
{  
   "Login":{  
      "childNodes":null,
      "children":null,
      "key":"Login",
      "subKey":{  
         "buffer":"Login",
         "offset":0,
         "length":5,
         "value":"Login",
         "hasValue":true
      },
      "isContainerNode":false,
      "rawValue":null,
      "attemptedValue":null,
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "exception":null,
            "errorMessage":"'Login' should not be empty."
         }
      ],
      "validationState":1
   },
   "Password":{  
      "childNodes":null,
      "children":null,
      "key":"Password",
      "subKey":{  
         "buffer":"Password",
         "offset":0,
         "length":8,
         "value":"Password",
         "hasValue":true
      },
      "isContainerNode":false,
      "rawValue":null,
      "attemptedValue":null,
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "exception":null,
            "errorMessage":"'Password' should not be empty."
         }
      ],
      "validationState":1
   }
}
```

`return ModelState.Select(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Errors).SelectMany(x => x.Select(z => z.ErrorMessage));` Output:

```
[  
   "'Login' should not be empty.",
   "'Password' should not be empty."
]
```

Comment: you want a simple linq query for select modelsatate error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this one

```
modelState.Keys.SelectMany(
    key => modelState[key].Errors
        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)).ToList()
```

Although, I do create a custom *ValidationError* class which ingests much more data, but this is the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var errorList = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors)
                                 .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
                                 .ToList();
```